# XML element with attribute and String content

Tags: xml, xsd

In XML Schema, how do I define a `ComplexType` that renders like the following?

```
<ValidationError code="X501">I love cats!</ValidationError>
```

If I try the following my tools* will say it is not valid

```
        <xsd:complexType name="ValidationErrorType">
            <xsd:attribute name="code" type="xsd:string"></xsd:attribute>
            <xsd:simpleContent>
                <xsd:extension base="xs:string"/>
            </xsd:simpleContent>
        </xsd:complexType>
```

Tools I use are Altova XMLSpy for visual editing and wsdl2java to generate classes

Update: I have tried [another flavour](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/el_simpleContent.asp)

```
        <xsd:complexType name="ValidationErrorType">
            <xsd:simpleContent>
                <xsd:extension base="xs:string">
                    <xsd:attribute name="code" type="xsd:string" />
                </xsd:extension>
            </xsd:simpleContent>
        </xsd:complexType>
```

Altova said `Invalid XML schema: 'Value 'xs:string' is not allowed for attribute 'base'.'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, I learned the lesson

1. Attributes can extend a `simpleContent` but **must** appear within the `extension`
2. I mistyped the `xsd` prefix in my second example which was almost correct

The correct form is

```
        <xsd:complexType name="ValidationErrorType">
            <xsd:simpleContent>
                <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
                    <xsd:attribute name="code" type="xsd:string" />
                </xsd:extension>
            </xsd:simpleContent>
        </xsd:complexType>
```